# How to diagnose and fix a flask/werkzeug reload error that crashes app immediately after startup

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Starting my application results in a crash immediately after startup.  It isn't clear what the error could mean, as it has just loaded the module it claims not to find.

It might be a red-herring, but why would it immediately restart?

Most other references I can find to this error message are when the file has been called as a script and not - as I already do - as a module (-m)

```
(.virtualenv3) rob@positron:~/Projects/<my_proj>/codebase/src$ source ../../.webapp.env && python3 -m webapp.main
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8002/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
/home/rob/Projects/<myproj>/.virtualenv3/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'webapp.main' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp')
```

**Edit 1:** Here is some output to show that the calling method certainly works with python modules in the same package (albeit a basic test)

```
(.virtualenv3) rob@positron:~/Projects/<myproj>/codebase/src$ ls -la webapp/*.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob     0 Sep  9 15:37 webapp/__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob 11494 Dec 13 13:19 webapp/main.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 rob rob    19 Dec 13 13:36 webapp/test.py
(.virtualenv3) rob@positron:~/Projects/<myproj>/codebase/src$ python -m webapp.test
Hello SO  
(.virtualenv3) rob@positron:~/Projects/<myproj>/codebase/src$ python -m webapp.main
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8812/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:werkzeug: * Restarting with stat
/home/rob/Projects/<myproj>/.virtualenv3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'webapp.main' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp')
```

**Edit 2.** `PYTHONPATH=$(pwd) python -m ....` makes it work, but why is this needed? just to get werkzeug to play nice?

**EDIT 3. Diagnosed** *Flask* is changing the CWD of the process.

Here's a test file (`webapp/test.py`)

```
import os
print('cwd: ', os.getcwd())
from flask import Flask

Flask(__name__).run(port=9991, debug=True)
```

Watch the output of `os.getcwd()` change when werkzeug in debug mode reloads the app

```
(.virtualenv3) rob@positron:~/Projects/<myproj>/codebase/src$ PYTHONPATH=`pwd` FLASK_ENV=development python -m webapp.test
cwd: /home/rob/Projects/<myproj>/codebase/src
 * Serving Flask app "test" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:9991/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
cwd: /home/rob/Projects/<myproj>
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 134-807-518
```

This is because "if" you have dotenv available, Flask will run it and the assume the location of the .env file found is the root of the project and switches to that.

Thanks Flask.  No fix yet though.

https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/cli.py#L607

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/3444

Comment: Could you share your folder structure? I am pretty sure it is caused by where you calling the webapp.main script.

Comment: @KingDarBoja well it's a pretty large app, but of course it's already started ok so it certainley exists eh? Flask and Werkzeug have found the module and run it already.  Rest assured: It's at the root of the tree of all the modules; webapp/main.py exists; as does webapp/__init__.py  - something more specific as a telltale? thanks

Comment: Oddly it works fine in a docker container, and I'm trying to determine what is different.

Comment: Something like that happened to me in a docker container few days ago, the problem is indeed where are you calling the python file, it is being called on the parent folder where your file is located or at the same level? If you call on the parent, python can properly find the module because it is looking for some package named 'webapp' on some import.

Comment: thanks @KingDarBoja, i've updated the Q to show that I can call a sibling just fine, using the same mechanism.  Werkzeug seems to have a reloader, which cannot find the module on 2nd pass, or something.

Comment: it's down to an odd assumption in Flask changing the CWD

Comment: The last issue you provide does have a possible workaround: [You can disable automatic loading and set up the project manually instead.](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#disable-dotenv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `FLASK_SKIP_DOTENV=1`

to skip the `os.chdir()`